# Loop for Worksheets takes Longer with other Workbooks open

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

I have coded this project in which the last step is to loop through the Worksheets in this workbook and find and replace specific values with inputed values. However, when there is a second workbook open this take 1-2 minutes, but when it is just open by itself, it takes maybe 2 seconds (I have not timed it, just approximate). I am utilizng VBA on Excel 2013 and I have a feeling it is trying to loop through every worksheet available even in different Workbooks, but am unsure if this is true or not. I have isolated the time constraint to this piece of code:

```
Sub ButtonRun()

Dim varResponse As Variant

varResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to continue?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This action cannot be undone.", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
If varResponse = vbNo Then Exit Sub

If BoxAAA.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in AAA"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxBBB.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in BBB"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxCCC.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in CCC"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxDDD.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in DDD"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxEEE.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in EEE"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxFFF.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in FFF"
    Exit Sub
End If

If BoxGGG.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox "Please fill in GGG"
    Exit Sub
End If

If CheckA.Value = False And CheckB.Value = False And CheckC.Value = False _
    And CheckD.Value = False And CheckE.Value = False And CheckF.Value = False _
    And CheckG.Value = False And CheckH.Value = False And CheckI.Value = False _
    And CheckJ.Value = False And CheckK.Value = False And CheckL.Value = False _
    And CheckM.Value = False And CheckN.Value = False And CheckO.Value = False _
    And CheckP.Value = False And CheckQ.Value = False And CheckR.Value = False _
    And CheckS.Value = False And CheckT.Value = False And CheckU.Value = False _
    And CheckV.Value = False And CheckW.Value = False And CheckX.Value = False _
    And CheckY.Value = False And CheckZ.Value = False And ChekcAA.Value = False _
    And CheckBB.Value = False And CheckCC.Value = False And CheckDD.Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please select Checkboxes."
        Exit Sub
End If

Dim fname As String
Dim path As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
fname = BoxHHH.Value & ", " & BoxAAA.Value

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\Created\" & fname, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(fname)

If CheckA.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("A1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("A2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("A3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("A4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckB.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("B1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("B2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("B3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("B4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckC.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("C1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("C2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("C3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("C4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckD.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("D1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("D2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("D3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("D4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckE.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("E1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("E2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("E3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("E4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckF.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("F1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("F2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("F3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("F4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckG.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("G1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("G2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("G3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("G4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckH.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("H1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("H2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("H3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("H4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckI.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("I1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("I2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("I3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("I4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckJ.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("J1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("J2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("J3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("J4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckK.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("K1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("K2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("K3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("K4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckL.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("L1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("L2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("L3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("L4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckM.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("M1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("M2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("M3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("M4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckN.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("N1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("N2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("N3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("N4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckO.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("O1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("O2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("O3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("O4").Visible = True
End If


If CheckP.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("P1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("P2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("P3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("P4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckQ.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("Q1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Q2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Q3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Q4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckR.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("R1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("R2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("R3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("R4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckS.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("S1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("S2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("S3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("S4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckT.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("T1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("T2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("T3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("T4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckU.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("U1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("U2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("U3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("U4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckV.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("V1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("V2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("V3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("V4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckW.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("W1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("W2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("W3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("W4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckX.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("X1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("X2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("X3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("X4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckY.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("Y1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Y2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Y3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Y4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckZ.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("Z1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Z2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Z3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("Z4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckAA.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("AA1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("AA2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("AA3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("AA4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckBB.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("BB1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("BB2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("BB3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("BB4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckCC.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("CC1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("CC2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("CC3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("CC4").Visible = True
End If

If CheckDD.Value = True Then
    wb.Sheets("DD1").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("DD2").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("DD3").Visible = True
    wb.Sheets("DD4").Visible = True
End If

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="AAA", Replacement:=BoxAAA.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="BBB", Replacement:=BoxBBB.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="CCC", Replacement:=BoxCCC.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="DDD", Replacement:=BoxDDD.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="EEE", Replacement:=BoxEEE.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="FFF", Replacement:=BoxFFF.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="GGG", Replacement:=BoxGGG.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
    Next ws
UserFormDealerInfo.Hide

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible <> True Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

The Code that seems to causes the time constraint is:

```
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="AAA", Replacement:=BoxAAA.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="BBB", Replacement:=BoxBBB.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="CCC", Replacement:=BoxCCC.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="DDD", Replacement:=BoxDDD.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="EEE", Replacement:=BoxEEE.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="FFF", Replacement:=BoxFFF.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="GGG", Replacement:=BoxGGG.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
    Next ws
UserFormDealerInfo.Hide

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible <> True Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Answer (score 0):

```
If you have specified the Workbook name I dont think it will loop through other WB sheet. Try to debug the code see how it run. OR
Also you can use **'for next loop**' instead for each...

For r = 1 to activeworkbook.worksheets.count

 If worksheet(r).Visible = xlSheetVisible Then

  worksheets(r).Cells.Replace What:="AAA", Replacement:=BoxAAA.Value, LookAt _ :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _ ReplaceFormat:=False

End if

Next

Try this if it works.

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
I have modified your code a bit kindly check if it works.
Sub ButtonRun()

Dim varResponse As Variant

varResponse = MsgBox("Are you sure you wish to continue?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "This action cannot be undone.", vbYesNo, "Confirm")
If varResponse = vbNo Then Exit Sub

If (BoxAAA.Value = "") And (BoxBBB.Value = "") And (BoxCCC.Value = "") And (BoxDDD.Value = "") And _
    (BoxEEE.Value = "") And (BoxFFF.Value = "") And (BoxGGG.Value = "") Then
    MsgBox "Please fill all required boxes to Procees", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error"
    Exit Sub
End If

'you can put code here to loop through all checkboxes insetead of writing long code..I donw know
' u have created checkboxes in form or in worksheet..E.G.

'  Dim checkbxchk As Control
'
'  For Each checkbxchk In UserForm1.Controls
'    If checkbxchk.Name Like "Check*" Then
'      if checkbxchk.value = false then
'           MsgBox "Please select Checkboxes and try again."
 '               exit sub
'    End If
'  Next




If CheckA.Value = False And CheckB.Value = False And CheckC.Value = False _
    And CheckD.Value = False And CheckE.Value = False And CheckF.Value = False _
    And CheckG.Value = False And CheckH.Value = False And CheckI.Value = False _
    And CheckJ.Value = False And CheckK.Value = False And CheckL.Value = False _
    And CheckM.Value = False And CheckN.Value = False And CheckO.Value = False _
    And CheckP.Value = False And CheckQ.Value = False And CheckR.Value = False _
    And CheckS.Value = False And CheckT.Value = False And CheckU.Value = False _
    And CheckV.Value = False And CheckW.Value = False And CheckX.Value = False _
    And CheckY.Value = False And CheckZ.Value = False And ChekcAA.Value = False _
    And CheckBB.Value = False And CheckCC.Value = False And CheckDD.Value = False Then
        MsgBox "Please select Checkboxes."
        Exit Sub
End If

Dim fname As String
Dim path As String

path = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path
fname = BoxHHH.Value & ", " & BoxAAA.Value

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & "\Created\" & fname, FileFormat:= _
        xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks(fname)

'you already have validate that all checkboxes should be checked to run the code so no need to put condtion here
'to check if it is true or not
'use this code
For Each Sheet In wb.Sheets
        If Sheet.Name Like ("*1") Or (Sheet.Name = "*2") Or (Sheet.Name = "*3") Or (Sheet.Name = "*4") Then
            Sheet.Visible = True
           Else
           Sheet.Visible = False
        End If
Next

Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible Then
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="AAA", Replacement:=BoxAAA.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="BBB", Replacement:=BoxBBB.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="CCC", Replacement:=BoxCCC.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="DDD", Replacement:=BoxDDD.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="EEE", Replacement:=BoxEEE.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="FFF", Replacement:=BoxFFF.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
        ws.Cells.Replace What:="GGG", Replacement:=BoxGGG.Value, LookAt _
            :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
            ReplaceFormat:=False
    End If
    Next ws
UserFormDealerInfo.Hide

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws1 In wb.Worksheets
    If ws1.Visible = False Then
        ws1.Delete
    End If
Next ws1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Save

End Sub
```

Comment: Going through every step and you are right, this does not seem to jump to the other workbook at all to do the replace functions. So that does not seem to be the problem.

I tried your code above, but the problem still persists. Running it without other workbooks open is immediate, but as soon as another is open. It takes more than a minute to run. Once again stepping through it, I cannot find a place in which it tries to replace in the other workbook.

Comment: Is this your full code? May be problem is somwhere else in the code. Try to find where it creates problem when other workbook is open. Or you can share full code if there is no privacy issue.

Comment: This is not full code, but full code would create a privacy issue. This code is off a userform and this section is what is causing the problem. I have tried the other sections of the code with multiple sheets open and the problem does not exist unless this section of code is included. I am at a lost for why this could be occurring. I am assuming because it has to decide which workbook to go to every time the loop restarts. Even though, I have it defined.

Comment: No if you have defined a wb it will not run outside the workbook, Right now I am out of the town will revert tomorrow with some help. How many worksheets are there in the workbook? Or could you plz share the dummy  workbook only without code and userform with dummy data in it.

Comment: So I will be sharing the full code. It is now above. Like I said, the loops are what are causing the time crunch (As you can see there is now a second loop in the code) I have tried reversing the order of the loops and it does not speed up the process when there is more than one workbook open. I have edited the original question with the full code. And as I had stated, the loops are what cause the problems. The workbook itself has 121 sheets. The other workbook can be blank with 1 sheet or have 12 sheets, and it does not seem to matter, based on the time it takes.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the code will rewrite the code and send it to you after testing it give me some time will get back to you by tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for rewriting the code, Just a few notes. Not all checkboxes have to be checked, but at least one does. I believe your rewrite will still work, but as for the other conditions, I need them all, unless you see a better way, because I only unhide sheets if the corresponding checkbox is checked. The code still takes a longer time (minutes not seconds) when another workbook is open versus the almost immediate response when it is the only workbook open. I don't know if there is an answer for this truthfully. Thank you for all the help though.

Comment: Hmmm but still there will be something for this delay in runtime, instead of using cells.replace try range("A1").currentregion to replace the value and see if it works.

Comment: Hey I think your declaration for dim ws as worksheet is causing the problem remove that because in for each ws in wb.worksheets you dont have to declare ws it will automatically consider it as sheet..try this hope this will work for you.

Comment: Tried removing the Dim ws as Worksheet and the lag time is still existent.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late but thought I'd share for anyone else having the same issue. I had a similar issue with find/replace taking longer with another workbook open and managed to fix it by deleting some graphs and data tables from the other workbook. I found them by deleting sheets one at a time and re-testing the find and replace. Not sure why they'd be slowing down the process but give it a try.